# Argument list too long with grep

Tags: perl, find, grep

Normally to search and replace a string in a selection of files, I would find with:

```
grep -rl 'pattern' .
```

This works fine unless you have a LOT of matches.

Anyway, I was looking around and found a suggestion of using `find` instead:

```
find /root/path -type f -exec grep -l 'FIND' {} +
```

This works fine, but when I try and pass it into Perl to do the replacement, I get the error still:

```
perl -p -i -e 's|FIND|REPLACE|g' `find /root/path -type f -exec grep -l 'FIND' {} +`

-bash: /usr/local/bin/perl: Argument list too long
```

Is there any way around this?

Comment: Redirect to a file, then read that file line by line calling your perl command/script with it

Comment: Type `man xargs` into your terminal window

Comment: @ivanivan ah ok, so there isn't a one liner you can do?

Comment: @JennyD thanks - not sure how that helps though?

Comment: Not really... MOST programs have a max of 255 arguments, this is the limit you are hitting....

Comment: @ivanivan mmm ok, although I'm sure I've gone well over that limit before (as I've run greps on thousands of files). Anyway, maybe I'll give it a go like you suggested with a .cgi script that reads the piped values, and then do the regexp replacement on it manually

Comment: Not sure if this affects the set of commands you are running but I've read somewhere that using `+` in grep add as many files as possible as args to it at once while using `\;` executes grep every time a match is found.

Comment: @BryanCS - thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately it didn't work (same error about the argument list being too long)

Comment: @ivanivan thanks for the tip. I've written a little script (below) and shared it so hopefully, others can benefit as well. It's pretty simple, and does the job pretty efficiently :)

Comment: why not use just `sed`?

Comment: @alexus, won't that just have the same problem though? ;)

Comment: I dont think so... sed is *stream* editor, I think it'd run much faster as well.

Comment: @alexus - ah ok, interesting! I will give it a go when I next need to do a large grep :) (I've already done the stuff I needed to, with the script below, but its good to have a cleaner option for the future)

Comment: BTW, I assume I would run it in a similar way? `sed -i 's/$find/$replace/g'  \`find $path -type f -exec grep -l '$find' {} +\``

Comment: @alexus - I gave it a go, but still get an error: `-bash: /bin/sed: Argument list too long`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by people, I needed to write a little script to do the magic for me :)

For me, I have a LOT of files - so to help speed things up (and make the `find` a bit nicer on the server), I have split mine into multiple processes for the larger folders. So the script is:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

my $find = q|string-to-find|;
my $replace = q|replace-with|;

my @paths = split /\n/, q|/home/user/folder1
/home/user/folder2
/home/user/folder3
/home/user/folder4|;

my $debug = 1;

foreach my $path (@paths) {
    my @files = split /\n/, `find $path -type f -exec grep -l '$find' {} +`;

    foreach (@files) {
        chomp;
        if (-f $_) {
            print qq|Doing $_\n| if $debug > 0;
            `sed -i 's/$find/$replace/g' $_`
        }

    }

}
```

Then just run it from SSH with:

```
perl script-name.cgi
```